# How to take Incremental backup for Azure SQL db using SQLPackage

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created a devOps pipeline which executes a task using SQLPackage which takes the backup of our SQL DB in .bacpac file. This export took almost 5 hours to complete. As we are going to take the Production DB backup every night, we want to take only incremental DB backup instead of Full Backup.

Can you please guide me how we can do that using SQLPackage or suggest some other options

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Hi @sac, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure SQL Database supports Full backup, Differential backup and Transaction log backup**.

**Differential backup**: - `It is based on the latest full data backup. it only collects the data which are changed after the last full data backup. You may routinely backup your database without experiencing the burden of complete database backups`.

***Azure SQL Database provides automated backups***.

> **Full Data Backup - every week;
> Differential backup - every 12-24 hours;
> Transaction log backup- every 5 to 10 minutes.**

Reference: -
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=single-database**